# Fotorama - how to increase spacing between thumbnails

Tags: fotorama

I need to increase the spacing between the thumbnails.  How do I do this?

I only have 5 images, and it is looking funny with the thumbs all bunched up in the center.

Many thanx.

Comment: I sloved it https://stackoverflow.com/a/56128275/8251894
You just have to add thumbmargin in app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml

Answer (score 5):

Just use `thumbmargin` option:

```
<div class="fotorama"
     data-nav="thumbs"
     data-thumbmargin="10">
  <img src="1.jpg">
  <img src="2.jpg">
</div>
```

http://fotorama.io/customize/options/#thumbmargin

Answer (score 1):

In the site I'm working on, I did it by adding the margin-right value to the selector below:

```
.fotorama__nav--thumbs .fotorama__nav__frame {
padding-left: 0!important;
margin-right: 14px;
}
```

Obviously you can amend this value to whatever suits you.

A problem with this approach is that the blue border which indicates which thumbnail is currently selected, has its animation set with CSS3 from within the fotorama JS file. I wasn't able to get this to animate over the increased margin.

My solution was to add this line which maintains the blue border, forgoing the animation:

```
.fotorama__nav__frame.fotorama__active div{ 
    width: 60px; height: 60px; border: solid 2px #00afea;
}
```

Hope this helps you ;)